# Easy vanilla JS SPA routing - what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, url-routing, single-page-application

I am trying to implement client side routing for my SPA. I know there are libraries like page.js to help with this, but I want to implement it myself so that I can learn how it works. I seem to have it working but it was a lot easier than I thought it would be so I am worried I have missed something. The steps I have taken are:

1. I have set my server to always return `index.html`.
2. `index.html` has links for example `<a href="/home"></a>` to each page.
3. on initial page load, grab the URL from `window.location.pathname` and render the correct page.
4. add click handler to each link which does: `event.preventDefault()`, add the page to history with `window.history.pushState()`, and then finally render the relevant page.
5. listen to `popstate` event and render associated page, to handle back and forward browser buttons.

So I have initial page load/page refresh which correctly renders whatever URL is in the address bar, and the back and forward navigation buttons work thanks to `pushState()` and the `popstate` listener. Am I missing something? Why do people use `#` URLs when it seems trivial to just prevent page reload with `event.preventDefault()`? Thanks!

Comment: its not about Why do people use `#`, the real issue comes when its more than hello page a, b, c etc like adding and removing event handlers at the right time for the page content, also SPA doesn't mean its developed in a single file.

Comment: The hash approach is just another way to do it that predates the history API. Just because you can use the `popstate` instead of `onhashchange` doesn't mean everyone is going to use `popstate` or that there is no merit to the hash approach. There are compatibility, historical and semantic issues. You could use query params as well to implement a SPA as GitHub does with `?tab=repositories`.